# Swift: Trying to make a app that counts down the time from the present until one hour later

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an app that tell us the rest of time from the present time till one hour later.

This is the code but now it only has a function that tell us the countdown time by decreasing one second from the present time.

I'm thinking that I haven't definite the definition of the "cnt" 
so that's why I'm thinking it doesn't work.

Can somebody tell me the reason and a solution?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var cnt : Int = 0
var timer : NSTimer!//NSTimerというデフォルト機能から引っ張る
var myInt:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let myDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    let myCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let myComponents = myCalendar.components([.Year, .Hour, .Minute, .Second],
        fromDate: myDate) // myDate、すなわちNSDateから要素として引っ張り出してる

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "onUpdate:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)//カウントダウンのインターバル
    timer.fire()

    var myStr: String = "\(myComponents.hour)"
    myStr += "\(myComponents.minute)"
    myStr += "\(myComponents.second)"

    myInt = Int(myStr)! // toInt()がSwift2より無効になったようです。myInt=Str(my components,hour,minute,second)=現時刻

}

func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer){
    cnt += 1//cnt+1=cnt,
    let count = myInt - cnt //残り時間＝現在時刻ー現在時刻に１時間足した時刻
    print(count) // println()は、Swift2よりDeprecatedになりました。
}

}
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it.  Instead, set a target date, and whenever we want to update our UI, calculate the difference between now and the current time.  We cannot guarantee that exactly 1 second has ticked by between every call of `onUpdate()`.  However, we can easily calculate when 1 hour from now is (exactly), and we can easily calculate the exact amount of time between now and some point in the future.

Comment: just add 3600 (seconds = 1 hour) to the total time

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what you're asking, but I will do my best.

In your `viewDidLoad` method, you're setting `myInt` to the integer representation of `myStr`. If the time is 18:30:50, `myInt` will be equal to `183050`. That is not an appropriate representation of the time. Time is base 60, integers are base 10, for one thing. If you want to represent time as a single number, you can use `timeIntervalSinceDate`, or `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` or `timeIntervalSince1970` to get the `NSTimeInterval` (ie. fractional seconds) representation of the date relative to a certain epoch either of your choosing or one built into Foundation.

Subtracting 1 from myInt each time the timer fires isn't going to give you an indication of the time remaining.

Also, `NSTimer` is not an accurate way to keep time. You should instead save the start date as a property and determine the time remaining based on `timeIntervalSinceDate`

e.g.

```
func onUpdate(timer : NSTimer){
    let currentTime = NSDate()
    let timeElapsed = currentTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(myDate)
    println(timeElapsed)
}
```

If you want to show time elapsed in minutes, you can divide it by 60. You can look into [NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html) to easily get a string representation of time intervals.

If you want the countdown to stop after an hour, then check for when `timeElapsed` is over 3600.

If you want it to show a countdown from 1 hour, then subtract the `timeElapsed` from 3600.

Comment: I'd do this in the opposite way.  It's less abstract.  The start time is entirely irrelevant.  If we're counting down, we only care about what instant we're counting down to.  The instant we're counting down from stops mattering the instant we've calculated the time we're counting to.

Comment: You mean get an NSDate that is 1 hour into the future and use that as the time reference?

Comment: For this specific question, yes basically.

Comment: Well, it's a semantic difference. Bit simpler in the timer fire method but more work in the setup. Both fairly trivial though.

Comment: You only consider it a semantic difference because your code sample is calculating & printing `timeElapsed`.  You're ignoring what the asker is attempting to do (print the time left until a certain time).  Your approach requires keeping an extra variable (time started and time to count down versus just time to count to) and it requires an extra calculation each time you want to print (time since started minus time to count down instead of just time until time we're counting to)